# CSS селекторы разделенные точкой

Tags: css, вёрстка, css-selectors

Скажите, пожалуйста, что означает вот такая запись:

```
.class1.class2 .class3 {

}
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors

Comment: спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: был рад помочь)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элемент с двумя классами одновременно, в котором вложен третий:

```css
.class1.class2 .class3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
    <div class="class3">
        Тест
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли